# Golang code to check if first word can be formed from second word

Tags: go

I tried below golang code to check if first string can be formed from second string. Is there any improvement that can be done on this code?

```
package main
import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

func main() {

    words := []string{"hello", "ellhoo"}

    result := "NO"

    s := words[0]
    for i := 0; i < len(words[0]); i++ {
        if strings.Contains(words[1], string(s[i])) == false {
            result = "NO"
            break
        } else {
            result = "YES"
            words[1] = strings.Replace(words[1],string(s[i]),"",1)
        }
    }
    fmt.Println(result)

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Record the count of each rune in the source string in a map.  For each rune in the target string, fail if count in map is zero. Decrement count.

Here's the code:

```
// canmake reports whether t can constructed from the runes in s.
func canmake(t, s string) bool {
    m := map[rune]int{}
    for _, r := range s {
        m[r]++
    }
    for _, r := range t {
        if m[r] == 0 {
            return false
        }
        m[r]--
    }
    return true
}
```

Here's an example showing how to use it:

```
func main() {
    fmt.Println(canmake("hello", "ellhoo"))
    fmt.Println(canmake("hello", "elhoo")) // insufficent number of l
    fmt.Println(canmake("hello", "elloo")) // mising h
}
```